# Javascript Datejs library: range error

Tags: javascript, date, datejs, daterangepicker

I'm using [Datejs - js date library](http://www.datejs.com/) and i have a function:

```
var initDateRangePicker = function() {
console.log(Date.today());
    $('.date-range').daterangepicker(
            {
                opens: (App.isRTL() ? 'left' : 'right'),
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                separator: ' do ',
                startDate: Date.today().add({
                    months: -1
                }),
                endDate: Date.today(),
                minDate: '01/01/2013',
                maxDate: '31/12/2054'
            }
    );
    console.log({a: Date.today()});
};
```

Daterangepicker is initialized with correct values (`Date.today()` and `Date.today().add({months:-1})`)
Unfortunately, in console I have in both cases RangeError. Why? Please, help.

Comment: Can you re-create it in a fiddle?

Comment: Please note that [datejs is abandoned](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).  Consider using [Gregory's fork](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/), or switching to [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just ran the DateJS part of your code (disclaimer: I maintain an active, and heavily updated, fork of DateJS)...

Doesn't seem to be any problem in the DateJS code - at least in my fork - as I'm getting zero errors created the object you pass into the picker. Perhaps it's a problem with the `daterangepicker` plugin?